# git switch which branch is master branch after push

Tags: git

I have a fork of someone else's repo like and have committed a number of changes to my master branch like so, and pushed to my fork:

```
[upstream/master] --- C1 --- C2[origin/master]
```

I then decided that I want my changes `C1` and `C2` to be part of a branch `feature_branch1`, and I want my `master` branch to be back at `upstream/master`:

```
[upstream/master === origin/master] --- C1 --- C2[origin/feature_branch1]
```

I achieved this via:

```
git checkout C2
git branch -m feature_branch1
git checkout upstream/master
git branch -m master
```

(don't know if that was the way I was meant to do it).

I then added some extra features off my `master` branch like so:

```
                                     C1 --- C2 [origin/feature_branch1]
                                   / 
[upstream/master === origin/master]
                                   \ 
                                     C1' --- C2' [origin/feature_branch2]
```

(`git checkout master; git checkout -b feature_branch2; <changes>; <commits>`)

Now I'm trying to push to remote. I've pushed `feature_branch1` and `feature_branch2` successfully (`git push origin feature_branchX`), but when I try to push master I get an error about not being able to fast forward and losing history.

I kind of get this - I think it doesn't want me to lose `C1` and `C2` by moving `master` back to the branch-point. But I've saved `C1` and `C2` in `feature_branch1` already, so I won't lose them.

Is there any way I can achieve the diagram above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `--force` flag to your push it should succeed.

Rewriting history is considered a bad thing once pushed because if someone else has cloned your master and pulled the commits you are removing, they will encounter problems since they have refs that no longer exist.

Comment: That's the thing - am I actually removing them? I don't think I am, beacuse the commits with the same SHA numbers are still there, but just under branch `feature` instead of `master`, since all I did was rename my branch? or am I getting confused

Comment: You are removing them from the master branch. If someone has pulled the latest refs for your master branch, they will encounter errors in the future, even though those same commits now exist in a different branch. The point is just that you should be careful with that flag, not that you 100% should never use it. I've used it. I've rewritten history after publicly pushing. Just be careful when doing so and understand that it can affect other people. It's up to you to evaluate whether it's appropriate to do in a given situation.

Answer (score 1):

After a `git checkout master`, you can do `git reset --hard origin/master` to reset your branch to the same state as the remote master.

Comment: Yes, but my origin/master is currently at C2 and I'd like it to be at upstream/master. That's my problem.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the question... I'll delete this answer in a few minutes, the one by @cjc343 seems to be what you want